# Error for converting some specific date in persian calendar format

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, persian-calendar

We have website that everybody can add a record witch includes date column
everytime the add a record to database a date will save in date column
and when they want to see them in a gridview, it will be convert in persian calendar format

The problem is that some specific dates can not convert.for example if we want to convert date 1398/6/31 to Gregorian date, It will give an error

```java
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime date = System.DateTime.Today;
    System.Globalization.PersianCalendar p = new 
    System.Globalization.PersianCalendar();
    int year = p.GetYear(date);
    int month = p.GetMonth(date);
    int day = p.GetDayOfMonth(date);
    System.DateTime currentDate = new System.DateTime(1398, 6, 31);
    azsh.Text = currentDate.ToString("d/M/yyyy");
}
```

Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an unrepresentable DateTime.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: I don't think this question is related to SQL, so I suggest removing the tag.

Comment: @Sach The problem is that some specific dates can not convert.for example if we want to convert date 1398/6/31 or 1398/2/31 to Gregorian date, It will give an error

Comment: @Hilarion This problem exists on asp.net